# How to stop the data in my variables moving to a new line with JSON in python

Tags: python

I am trying to keep my data from variable on the same line when its output in JSON, here is my code -

```
import json
numbers = [2,'g',5,2,'k',1,'a',5,7,'o',9,8,'h',3,4,'e',4,10,'y']

def remove_duplicates(duplist):
    noduplist = []
    for element in duplist:
        if element not in noduplist:
            noduplist.append(element)
        
    return noduplist

from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for x in remove_duplicates(numbers):
    d[type(x)].append(x)

number = (d[int])
letters = (d[str])

number.sort()
letters.sort()
list = (number + letters)
total = sum(number)
string_count = len(letters)


output = {"List": list, "total": total, "string_count": string_count, "integers": number, "strings": letters}

print(json.dumps(output, indent=2))
```

Its out put is -

```
{
  "List": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10,
    "a",
    "e",
    "g",
    "h",
    "k",
    "o",
    "y"
  ],
  "total": 49,
  "string_count": 7,
  "integers": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10
  ],
  "strings": [
    "a",
    "e",
    "g",
    "h",
    "k",
    "o",
    "y"
  ]
}
```

But i need it to look like this  -

"list": [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,'a','e','g','h','k','o','y']

Where am i going wrong? I have searched forums and documentation but cant see how to stop it

Comment: I am new to python so still learning, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

First, you are printing an `object` that have multiple keys (List, total, string_count etc). Printing that object will always display all the keys and values you put into that object.

If you only want the `List` part of that object, you should print that specific key, like so:

`print(json.dumps(output["List"]))`

Output:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, "a", "e", "g", "h", "k", "o", "y"]`

You don't have to use `json.dumps`, you can just `print(output["List"]` with the following result:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'a', 'e', 'g', 'h', 'k', 'o', 'y']`

Note the difference: the former is valid json (using double quotes on strings) and the second is just a python list (using single quotes on strings).

Lastly, printing with an `indent=2` will result in a more readable form of your object (or in your case, an undesirable format).